# Help with Exercise 9.11 from Bishop's PRML book

Tags: machine-learning, self-study

Exercise 9.11 from Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" asks

> Show that in the limit $\epsilon\to0$, maximizing the expected complete-data log likelihood for the Gaussian mixture model in which all components have covariance $\epsilon I$, given by (9.40),
>   $$
> \mathbb{E}_Z[\ln p(X,Z|\mu,\Sigma,\pi)] = \sum_n \sum_k \gamma(z_{nk}) \bigl\{ \ln\pi_k + \ln\mathcal{N}(x_n|\mu_k,\Sigma_k) \bigr\}
> \tag{9.40}
> $$
>   is equivalent to minimizing the distortion measure $J$ for the $K$-means algorithm given by (9.1)
>   $$
> J = \sum_n \sum_k r_{nk} \|x_n-\mu_k\|^2.
> \tag{9.1}
> $$

I agree that $\gamma(z_{nk})\to r_{nk}$ as $\epsilon\to0$. But I could not derive the equation (9.43)
$$
\mathbb{E}_Z[\ln p(X,Z|\mu,\Sigma,\pi)] \to -\frac{1}{2} \sum_n \sum_k r_{nk} \|x_n-\mu_k\|^2 + \text{const}
\tag{9.43}
$$
as $\epsilon\to0$. Any comment is welcome.

> I leave an answer here for a reference in future.
>
> **Answer:** (with the help of [KDG](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/212274/kdg))
>
> The equation (9.43) in the book is not correct. The correct one is
>   $$
> \epsilon\cdot\mathbb{E}_Z[\ln p(X,Z|\mu,\Sigma,\pi)] \to -\frac{1}{2} \sum_n \sum_k r_{nk} \|x_n-\mu_k\|^2
> $$
>   as $\epsilon\to0$. (See [stats.stackexchange.com/a/129918/212274](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129918/212274) for further discussion.)

Comment: Is there any possibility if the definition of distance is $\| x_n-\mu_k\|^2=( x_n-\mu_k)'\Sigma^{-1}( x_n-\mu_k)$ as Mahalanobis distance?  If it is. Just putting the pdf of multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(x_n|\mu_k,\Sigma_k) $ would lead to the equation 9.43 because  $-1/2 \| x_n-\mu_k\|^2$ is the exponent of the pdf.  I am not good at Machine learning so I could be wrong.

Comment: @KDG Thanks for your comment. The definition of distance is surely $\|x_n-\mu_k\|^2=(x_n-\mu_k)^T(x_n-\mu_k)$. Actually the problem is that $-1/(2\epsilon)\|x_n-\mu_k\|^2$ is the exponent of the pdf because the covariance matrix $\Sigma_k=\epsilon I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: The problem is that $\epsilon$ is missing, right? May I recommend you to check out this link? : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129918/212274. Maybe it's kind of typo. I guess the equation should be $\epsilon \mathbb{E}_Z[\ln p(X,Z|\mu,\Sigma,\pi)] \to -\frac{1}{2} \sum_n \sum_k r_{nk} \|x_n-\mu_k\|^2 + \text{const}$ which has $\epsilon$ at first.

Comment: @KDG Thank you very much for the link. That's exactly what I want to find. I agree your answer that the expectation in (9.43) must have $\epsilon$ at first. Then I could finish here with the answer that **the equation (9.43) is not correct**.